# C# regex to strip value enclosed in XML element

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to figure out how to write a regex that will strip out the values enclosed in an xml tag.  For example,

```
string xml = "<MyElement1 attribute="bla"><MyElement1>12345</MyElement1></MyElement1>"
```

I want to know how to do the following:

- match on `MyElement1` nodes that do not have an attribute

So specifically, using my example I would match `<MyElement1>12345</MyElement1>` and replace `<MyElement1>` and `</MyElement1>` so that my final node looks like this: `<MyElement1 attribute="bla">12345</MyElement1>`

I've tried:  `[<][^>]*[>]` but this matches on all elements.  I'm not sure how to specify specific elements I want to match on.

I have made edits to make the question more focused and clearer as suggested based on the downvotes. I understand that I can use parse and navigate my document tree, but I prefer to use a regex replace of some sort because I want to apply this logic to any number of xml files with different tree structures, elements, and attributes.

Comment: You need to use an XML parser.  XML is not "regular" and regular expressions don't part is very well

Comment: why don't you read it using XElement, XDocument?

Answer (score 1):

Well you really don't need to use regular expressions, you just need to parse your XML using an XML parser.

One of the options you have would be to use the [`XDocument.Parse( xml )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2) method and [`XElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement?view=netframework-4.7.2), where the first would be to parse the string, and the second to read it's tag and it's value. An example for reading it would be the following one

```
string xml = "<MyElement1>12345</MyElement1><MyElement2>abcd</MyElement2><MyElement3>12345</MyElement3><MyElement4>12345</MyElement4>";
// wrap your element in a rootnode (you seem to be missing one in your example)
var document = XDocument.Parse( $"<root>{xml}</root>");
// get the root node and loop over it's children (cast XNode to XElement in the process)
foreach (var node in document.Root.Nodes().OfType<XElement>()) {
  // name is tag, value is well, it's value
  Console.WriteLine($"{node.Name}: {node.Value}");
}
```

Note that for the example to parse the document correctly, you must add a rootnode, as xml can have only one rootnode in the document. In my sample, I enclosed the rootnode during the parsing

This sample code uses the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace, so don't forget to import that one.

One additional comment would be that your supplied XML code had an error in it (`MyElemen4` opening tag with `MyElement4` closing tag)

Comment: This is an interesting way to approach it. But my XML is far more complicated than the sample I provided.  I have several nested nodes.  The particular nodesI want to access are 4 or 5 levels below the root.  How can I access those and can I actually modify them?  I.e delete a node that I specify but keep it's value?

Comment: Yeah, XElement has nodes again so you can kinda deep search in them. Both XElement and XDocument can save their structure, so you should be fine there ;) For the rest, have a look at the links I have supplied, the give some other methods you can use for going through the document. If you know the document structure beforehand, then the good old XmlSerializer would also do ofcourse

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a XML Parser but if you want, you can use a simple regex like `<([\w]*)>(.*?)<\/[\w]*>`, this would return the name of the tag and the value inside.

Output:

```
Match 1
Full match  0-30    <MyElement1>12345</MyElement1>
Group 1.    1-11    MyElement1
Group 2.    12-17   12345
Match 2
Full match  30-59   <MyElement2>abcd</MyElement2>
Group 1.    31-41   MyElement2
Group 2.    42-46   abcd
Match 3
Full match  59-89   <MyElement3>12345</MyElement3>
Group 1.    60-70   MyElement3
Group 2.    71-76   12345
Match 4
Full match  89-118  <MyElemen4>12345</MyElement4>
Group 1.    90-99   MyElemen4
Group 2.    100-105 12345
```

Keep in mind it doesn't take in consideration of tag attributes. If you want to fetch a specific tag you can replace `[\w]` with the tag name you want.